# I am using ngb Pagination in my angular app but it is not working properly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have applied NGB Pagination on my angular app in a table, but it is not working. It is just showing 2 pages and not dividing the data between pages of table. My code is below:

```
import { UserService } from './../services/user.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfo } from 'src/app/models/user-info';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserData();

  }


userData=[
{"name":"Akash","email":"akash@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"sumit","email":"sumit@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"mohit","email":"mohit@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"rajesh","email":"rajesh@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"ramesh","email":"ramesh@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"vikas","email":"vikas@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"suresh","email":"suresh@gmmail.com"},
{"name":"ramesh","email":"ramesh@gmmail.com"},
];

elementPerpage:number=5;
currentPage:number=1;
arrayLength:number=this.userData.length;
  userInfo:UserInfo[];
```

this my Html File

```
<h3>User Details</h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">User Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngIf="!userData || userData.length === 0">
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">No records</td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let info of userData">
                <td>
                    {{info.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                   {{info.email}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div >
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="arrayLength" [(page)]="currentPage" [pageSize]="elementPerpage">
    </ngb-pagination>
</div>
```

I have added Bootstrap to the project there no errors. But pagination is not working. How can I make ngb pagination work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please take a look at [the pagination docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview).
The basic usage example:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
    <!-- content here -->
  </tr>
</table>

<ngb-pagination
  [(page)]="page"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [collectionSize]="items.length"></ngb-pagination>
```

***ngFor** contains an answer (:

Comment: your answer is correct but can you please tell me that why we are using slice pipe here, what is the significance of using this?

Comment: it cuts the data for the selected page from the whole data massive. The pagination component provides developers with UI to select the current page. Displaying just the data for the current page is still the developer's responsibility.

Comment: Please note that without slice pipe page will not change.

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a life saver! It was about to go insane.